# How to not pay for a song twice?

Tags: itunes, mp3

What is an easy way to move a song I bought from iPhone 3 to iPhone 4 to iPad?

Do I need to move some files such as `Mvx034f.mp3` over somewhere and rename it?

I think the only other way is to let Apple know I want to download it one more time, but that is ONE TIME ONLY.

Quite often, I leave the song in my iPhone 3 or iPod, and the old computer, and 2 years later, I want to hear that song again.  With a CD, that's no problem.  With the iTunes purchase = Pay Again and I want to avoid it.

Comment: If purchase a CD, I can't go back to the store two years later and get another one without paying again.

Comment: I think this is a legitimate question, but the tone is argumentative :-(.

Comment: @g but I can take the CD I bought and listen to it again -- you trash all your CDs?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The best thing to do is to make sure that you set up a proper sync relationship with all of your devices. If you buy something on the iPhone3, then sync it, iTunes will copy it back to your library on your Mac / PC.

After that, you'll be able to synchronize it back to other devices that are connected as long as they are authorized to play it if the song is protected with FairPlay.

Comment: so what if I buy a new computer and want to put the old computer in the basement or sell it?

Comment: Copy all of your music to an External hard drive, then copy it to the new one. Once it's on the computer, a song is just an ordinary file that can go from machine to machine. Or use Time Machine, or the Mac's Migration Assistant. Lots of options available.

Comment: I see.  Will ask Apple to let me download and try the external hard drive method.  But i wonder what if i buy more things and 5 years later my computer hard drive crashed and i need to download those new purchases, will Apple say, you have already used your last download...  Amazon let users buy songs and download any time later...

Comment: Apple currently does not have a "you can download it again for free feature." It is your responsibility to backup your media. iTunes for Windows will even alert you, "Do you want to back up your music?"